# How to draw the lattice diagram in latex?

Tags: diagrams, lattice

I want to draw the following lattice diagram in latex :

[image]

---

I have tried to draw the lower diagram ABGFH with the following Tikz code:

```
    \[
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node (a) {A};
\node (b) [above of=a, left of=a] {F};
\node (c) [above of=a] {H};
\node (d) [above of=a, right of=a] {B};
\node (e) [above of=a, node distance = 4cm] {G};
\draw[-] (a) to (b);
\draw[-] (a) to (d);
\draw[-] (b) to (e);
\draw[-] (d) to (e);
\draw[-] (a) to (c);
\draw[-] (c) to (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

But it produced the following diagram:

[image]

But how to draw the whole diagram ?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I have got the following code:

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node (a) {A};
\node (b) [above of=a, left of=a] {F};
\node (c) [above of=a] {H};
\node (d) [above of=a, right of=a] {B};
\node (e) [above of=a, node distance = 4cm] {G};
\node (f) [above of=b] {E};
\node (g) [above of=d] {C};
\node (h) [above of=f, right of=f] {D};
\draw[-] (h) to (f);
\draw[-] (h) to (g);
\draw[-] (h) to (e);
\draw[-] (a) to (b);
\draw[-] (a) to (d);
\draw[-] (b) to (e);
\draw[-] (d) to (e);
\draw[-] (a) to (c);
\draw[-] (c) to (e);
\draw[-] (f) to (b);
\draw[-] (g) to (d); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

This worked nicely to produce the expected diagram.

**Edit 2:**

Now I want to go further. I want to draw 4 branches (AB, AC, AD, AE) as follows:

[image]

How to do that ? Should I use angle ?

Comment: Please provide a *complete* (but minimal) exemple. Also, your code doesn't compile (the Q node doesn't exist).

Comment: @Miyase, It was a mistake, Q is indeed `a`. I have corrected it. My code has shown error but produced the above diagram with only vertices, without edges

Comment: As I said in the first comment, please post a complete code. On this site it's called a MWE (Minimal Working Example) so that people willing to help can quickly copy and paste it for testing. Also, seeing your preamble can help debug specific situations.

Comment: Also, your code still doesn't compile, the `node` command on all the `\draw` lines probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Miyase, thanks. I corrected the code. It worked. But how to extend to whole diagram now ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP already provide a code which solve his problem. Only what can be suggested is how to write this code more concise.

Comment: @Zarko, Can you suggest how to write the code if we need 4 branch above the node `A` ?  Here we have only three branch AB, AH, AF. How to add more branch at the same height ?

Comment: You should edit question and clarify what is your  problem. So far after editing question, you actually solve your problem mentioned in the first version of question. Please proved a sketch what you aster. Now it is not clear.

Comment: @Zarko, please see the 2nd edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After second edit it is not clear what is other nodes above showed on image. I guess, that now you after the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 17mm and 17mm, on grid,
every node/.style = {circle, minimum size=1.2em, inner sep=0pt}
                        ]
\node (a) {A};
\node (b) [above right=of a] {B};
\node (c) [above=of b] {C};
\node (d) [above left=of c] {D};
\node (e) [below left=of d] {E};
\node (f) [below=of e] {F};
\node (g) [right=of e] {G};
%
\node (h) at ($(f)!0.3333)!(b)$) {H};
\node (i) at ($(f)!0.6666)!(b)$) {I};

\draw   (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (a)
        (a) -- (h) -- (g) -- (d) 
        (a) -- (i) -- (g)       
        (f) -- (g) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. yes I was looking something like that. Can you just explain the work of `\node (h) at ($(f)!0.3333)!(b)$) {H};` ?

Comment: @learner, it position node` h` at 1/3 distance between bode `f` and `b`. For details see `tikz` package documentation,  section *13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers*, page151.

Comment: Thanks. I got it clearly. Now I hope I can draw similar diagrams